# let q be an odd prime and p a prime dividing $1+n+\dots+n^{q-1}$

Tags: number-theory

let q be an odd prime and p a prime dividing $1+n+\dots+n^{q-1}$. Prove that $p = 1 \mod q$ or $p = q$.

I don't actually know how to start, i thought of using fermat's little theorem or an application of eulers formula, but it didn't really give me any insights.

Any hints?

Comment: Why not sum them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Note that the sum is equal to $\dfrac{n^q-1}{n-1}$ for $n \neq 1$ (treat $n=1$ separately).

Comment: Well if $p$ divides the sum, we can also say $p$ divides the numerator $n^q-1$. Now see if you can apply Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: maybe a little bit late, but do you have tips for proving that there are infinitly many primes of the form $p = 1\pmod{q}$?

Comment: @KeesTil your comment doesn't seem particularly relevant to this question but I'll give you a quick reply. The big theorem is Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions however the proof of this is rather complicated and goes through L-functions. Alternatively, a quick google search find me a proof of your special case using cyclotomic polynomials if you know about their properties - maybe start there.

Comment: no, it does not but i was just wandering about it :)